# Is the movie "Hell No" real?

Tags: trailer

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2697518/

All I ever see is the trailer. Is there a full movie?

I mean, why is it in IMDB then? Not all Youtube videos go to IMDB right?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a comedy/horror "short" and not science fiction/fantasy

Comment: `Budget: $6,000 (estimated)`... No, I'd say that's about it.  ([Video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olEbwhWDYwM))

Comment: Well, Hell no may be a real movie, but not that real. C'mon.

Comment: It was answered, but for continuity it should probably be migrated to the movies and tv beta SE site.

Answer (score 5):

> "Not all youtube videos go to imdb right?

Right - just the ones that someone submits to IMDB. Just about anyone can submit entries - both for films and for credits. IMDB can [reject the entries](https://secure.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?titletopfaq), but they don't actively seek out projects to add to their database.

It should be noted that even the IMDB link for [Hell No](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2697518/) lists the run time of the "movie" as **3 min** and that the categories are **Short**, **Horror** and **Comedy**.

So, even the IMDB page you link indicates that there is no "full movie" to go with the trailer.